# Intersection of Linear Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $\{a, a+b, a+2b,..., a+ib\}$ and $\{c, c+d, c+2d,..., c+jd\}$ where $a, b, c, d$ are natural (1+) and either $i$ or $j$ or both can be (a) finite or (b) infinite, how can I test whether the two sets intersect (i.e., test non-emptiness of the intersection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first the case where $b$ and $d$ are coprime.  Any $x$ in the intersection satisfies $x \equiv a \mod b$ and $x \equiv c \mod d$.  The general solution to this is $x = e + k b d$ where $e$ is one solution (which exists by the Chinese Remainder Theorem) and $k$ is an arbitrary integer.  You also want
$\max(a,c) \le e + k b d \le \min(a+ib,c+jd)$.  The condition for this is

$$ \left\lceil \dfrac{\max(a,c)-e}{bd} \right \rceil \le 
\left \lfloor \dfrac{\min(a+ib,c+jd)-e}{bd} \right \rfloor $$

If, on the other hand, $\gcd(b,d) = g > 1$, then an obvious necessary condition is that $g$ divides $a-c$.  If this is true, then by subtracting $a$ and dividing by $g$ we reduce to the previous case.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, I'm just not sure about the last part when $g>1$ where and why would $a$ be subtracted, after all the solution $x=e+kbd$ is independent of $a$? Wouldn't dividing $bd$ by $g$ be sufficient?

Comment: $e$ is dependent on $a$.  Let $b = g b'$,  $d = g d'$, $c - a = g c'$.  Then $x \equiv a \mod b$ and $x \equiv c \mod d$ iff $y \equiv 0 \mod b'$ and $y \equiv c' \mod d'$, where $y = (x-a)/g$.

Comment: Got it now, thanks